# Figure placement problems while using figure* in SAGE journal class

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I have written an two column article for SAGE journal. When SAGE compiled the document, the figures are placed in the wrong order. Figures with {figure} environment are placed in their proper positions, but figures with {figure*} are placed at the end of the document. Please help me resolve the problem.

MWE

```
%\documentclass[Afour,demo,sagev,times,doublespace]{sagej}

\documentclass[twocolumn,demo]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Figure-1a.eps}
        \caption{}\label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}
    %\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Figure-1b.eps}
        \caption{}\label{fig1b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Figure-1c.eps}
        \caption{}\label{fig1c}
    \end{subfigure}
    %\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Figure-1d.eps}
        \caption{}\label{fig1d}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{}\label{fig1}
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Figure-2.eps}
    \caption{}\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result should be that figure 1 should come before figure 2 . But SAGE placed the figure 2 first and placed figure 1 at the end of document.

Comment: figure* and figure were not kept in order with latex releases before 2015/01/01 unless you use the `fixltx2e` package. So if you have an old latex, add `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` as first line, or update your tex system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`figure*` and `figure` were not kept in order with latex releases before 2015/01/01 unless you use the `fixltx2e` package. So if you have an old latex, add `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` as first line, or update your tex system.

With TeXLive 2015 the example document has figure 1 on page 1 and figure 2 on page 2.